# What counts as an interruption for Primeval Awareness?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, unearthed-arcana

For the Revised Ranger from the Unearthed Arcana, they have a feature called Primeval Awareness, which has the following clause:

> By spending 1 uninterrupted minute in concentration (as if you were concentrating on a spell), you can sense whether any of your favored enemies are present within 5 miles of you.

What counts as an interruption for this purpose? For example, can the Ranger walk and talk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to interrupt 1 minute of concentration on an ability. The ability points out what rules to follow for this when it says (as if you were Concentrating on a spell)

Those can be found on PHB pg. 203

- Casting (another) spell that requires Concentration
- Taking damage and failing your Concentration (Constitution) Saving Throw.
- Being killed or afflicted with the Incapacitated status (also happens at 0 HP)
- Certain DM decided environmental phenomena
- Certain spells (such as Earthquake) that can potentially disrupt Concentration.

Nothing stops you from walking, talking, hunting, eating, or fighting while focusing (Concentrating) on Primeval Awareness. Sleeping might (I believe you are Incapacitated while sleeping, just like with the Sleep spell), but there are few normal every day actions that will interrupt this ability.

Comment: I can not quite find the relevant rule but...can you also activate this by concentrating for 1 minute during the 'light activity' part of a Long Rest that does not require that you actually sleep (particularly if you can Trance)?

Comment: It seems to me, then, that the Revised Ranger can always keep using Privemal Awareness to always be aware of where his or her Favored Enemies are, at all times.

Comment: Clearly not at *all* times. If the ranger is a melee ranger (2 weapon fighter) or the enemy closes on them or even damages them from range; a concentration save is not always going to pass. There are also Concentration spells like Hunters Mark that are important for the Ranger. They will rarely want to give up concentrating on that to use Awareness (because they have to choose which to concentrate on). To name a few examples.

Comment: Apologies, I may have said "always" and "at all times" too much there. I meant outside combat, the Revised Ranger can do a minute-by-minute ping of the surrounding 5 mile radius, to see if there are any Favored Enemies around.

Comment: @Markovchain *That* 'always' is accurate. Though, with this twice tested and released, re releases, and now Revised version of the Ranger being my favorite and often used; I do not see myself nor other rangers at tables I play with use this feature at every given moment. It (sadly) sits widely unused and forgotten until it dawns on them "Oh yea! I can use this. It'd be really handy right now!" . If the only abuse induced by this feature is almost always knowing where 1 or 2 creature types (of a list of 12+) are...then I think it's ok...

Comment: I actually like the idea of the Ranger being always aware of his prey. It sounds particularly useful for those with Humanoids as Favored Enemies. Nobody is sneaking around a Ranger (if they regard you as an enemy, at least).

Answer (score 6):

Since it indicates this is "as if you were concentrating on a spell", the rules for concentrating on a spell apply.

From p. 203 in the Player's Handbook:

> Normal activity, such as moving and attacking, doesn’t interfere with concentration.

Things that may interrupt your concentration are:

> - Casting another spell that requires concentration.
> - Taking damage. Whenever you take damage while you are concentrating on a spell, you must make a Constitution saving throw to maintain your concentration. The DC equals 10 or half the damage you take, whichever number is higher. If you take damage from multiple sources, such as an arrow and a dragon’s breath, you make a separate saving throw for each source of damage.
> - Being incapacitated or killed. You lose concentration on a spell if you are Incapacitated or if you die.

Also, the DM may determine that certain "environmental phenomena" may break your concentration. The player's handbook provides, as an example, a wave crashing over you on a storm tossed ship.